# How to convert a sequence into a streaming DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Having a sequence of strings `Seq[String]`, how can I convert it into a streaming DataFrame? The functions `SparkSession.createDataFrame(...)` create static DataFrames only. And the class `MemoryStream` only works for tests.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? For tests or exploring the api `MemoryStream` would be ok. And for a 'real' application what would be the problem with a static DataFrame when you have already a (fixed) sequence?

Comment: Because autoloader is s Databricks feature and closed-sourced, and I don’t want to depend on it.

Comment: That is a good point!

Comment: can you please add some sample input & expected output ?